# What are some good analogies I can use to explain ordinal numbers in an English translation?

Tags: pronunciación, inglés, números

I was recently having a conversation with my mother, who is Spanish-speaking only, after she was informed by someone who only spoke English that some work was going to be done on her street on the 20th. However, there was some confusion on both sides, because she had thought they said, *28th*. She asked, '28th?' And the guy said, 'Yeah.' So, she assumed it really was the 28th. Come to later find out that they actually meant the 20th! She was wholy unprepared for their visit and tried her best to adjust her plans accordingly.
In an attempt to explain the possible confusion, I tried to explain some equivalent pronunciations that people would use in Spanish for ordinal numbers like primero, segundo, tercero, etc., but I couldn't find any for 20 and beyond. I'm not sure how well she understands the English way of pronouncing numbers like that, though given that 20th and 28th might sound very similar, as well as any number like 40th or 50th, still, such instances might be rare.

I'm wondering if there are some good resources or simple explanations or analogies that my mother could benefit from, so that hopefully the mistake won't be repeated.

Comment: Keep in mind that, in Spanish, cardinal numbers are used in many cases where ordinals would be used in English.  If you wanted to translate the fifth of May into Spanish,  it would be el cinco de mayo.  The English is an ordinal.  The Spanish is a cardinal.

Comment: That's interesting because cardinals imply how much of something, so sinco de Mayo might sound like you have five of Mays. Likewise, if you use ordinals to describe the rank or order of something, could you theoretically say, el quinto de Mayo?

Comment: Think of it like in eng. we abbreviate/shorten "the day number five" to "the fifth," but in spa. we come from "el día número cinco" to "el cinco." So "el quinto de Mayo" would sound quite strange (if not wrong); a non-written rule, *any spanish-speaking culture only uses ordinals for the first day (primero/1ro/1º)*. A common (and one of the only) use we give to orinals is to *count the amount of times something happens/happened*. At [R.A.E - Ordinales](https://www.rae.es/dpd/ordinales) you have a quite complete list of them, e.g.: vigésimo (20º), trigésimo (30º), cuadragésimo (40º), and so on.